# Use process.env in html head

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a react app and I am using ms clarity for analytics. The docs say to set it up I need to use the javascript script tag in the head of the html. I am wondering if I can make an external file with the code and have access to the process.env.NODE_ENV variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Make the page mobile compatible -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



    <script type="text/javascript">
    
      if ('%NODE_ENV%' === 'production') {
        MS CLARITY CODE
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The node env variable is not working. I would like to have an external file that contains the clarity code and check if the app is in production so that it doesnt track changes when developing on localhost

Comment: If you want to use a custom HTML template, you'll want to make Webpack aware of it (so it can do things like interpolate `%NODE_ENV%`). If you're using Create React App, you could add script tag to ./public/index.html

Answer (score -2):

```
**try using this**
```

```html
<head>
      <title>React App</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       console.log("%REACT_APP_TEST%") // OK
       console.log("%NODE_ENV%") // development
      </script>
    </head>
```

```
and start server like this
 'NODE_ENV=development npm start'
```